# Calling a function once after tableview.reloadData

Tags: ios, uitableview

Every time I reload my table by calling

```
tableview.reloadData()
```

I want to call a specification function like

```
myFunction()
```

I was wondering, instead of stacking these two function next one after another everywhere in my code like

```
tableview.reloadData()
myFunction()
```

Is there a smart and clean way of calling myFunction every time tableview reloads?

Comment: You can call this function inside cellForRowAtIndexPath, Check last index of  row by using your last index of array that is assigned to numberOfRows, If last row occurs, then before returning cell just call your function. Happy Coding.

Answer (score 3):

There is no delegate method to give you a callback when reloadData() has completed, but to make it cleaner you could do a couple of different things.

You could create your own function like this:

```
func reloadTable() {
   tableView.reloadData()
   myFunction()
   //plus anything else you want to accomplish
}
```

Then you call that function everywhere in one line instead of repeating your code.

Alternatively, you could subclass `UITableView` and override the reloadData() method, adding your additional functionality.

Answer (score 0):

one way is to use inheritance. just implement your own tableview class and reload the reloadData function of UITableView.

```
class YourTableView: UITableView {
     override func reloadData() {
         super.reloadData()
         myFunction()
     }
     func myFunction() {
         //do something
     }
}
```

then declare YourTableView instead of UITableView

Comment: Sounds like a interesting idea. Can you please provide a small sample code for it?